# Getting last encoded file information from Apple Compressor

Tags: applescript, macos-catalina

So I'm a novice with AppleScript but learning a lot. I'm trying to create an AppleScript to let me know when Apple Compressor is finished encoding and notify me if it was successful or not. I have the part down about telling when compressor is done and the notification but having difficulty getting the file name and status (complete/fail/cancelled) from Compressor's history log.

Originally tried with UI scripting, but Compressor's window hierarchy list changes with every new encode. So now onto pulling it from the history log, which is in the user folder "Library/Application Support/" folder like this:

[image: file location]

And then, the file itself contains the status (whether it was successful or failed) near the bottom of the file like this:

[image: file contents]

So getting confused about how to A) find the last file and its name, and B) get the value of the last "ElementStatusState" in the document.

This is where I started but get errors when trying to resolve the path to the folder:

```
tell application "Finder"
  set latestFile to (last item of (sort (get files in folder "~/Library/Application Support/Compressor/History/V4" of application "System Events") by name)) as text
  set fileName to latestFile's name
end tell
```

This code throws an error about not being able to make it into the expected file type but also, I can see that It's grabbing a file that's not the last one modified.

In the end I want 2 variables that are 1) theFileName = ie name of encoded movie(s), and 2) theStatus = ie number 4,5, or 6)

Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to do something like the script below. This script finds the most recently modified file, then drills down through the plist file to find the various status numbers, and the names of the records they are logged in. I'm assuming that every file Compressor generates has the same structure; if not, you may find you have to alter the script. But this should give you an idea how to do that.

Names and status values are stored in the `nameList` and `valueList` variables, in order of depth.

```
set filePath to POSIX file "~/Library/Application Support/Compressor/History/V4"

-- sort the file list by modification date, then get the last item.
tell application "Finder"
    set mostRecentFile to last item of (sort files of folder filePath by modification date) as alias
end tell

set mostRecentFilePath to POSIX path of mostRecentFile

set nameList to {}
set valueList to {}

tell application "System Events"
    set plistFile to property list file mostRecentFilePath
    tell plistFile
        tell (first property list item whose kind is record)
            copy value of property list item "ElementInfoName" to end of nameList
            copy value of property list item "ElementStatusState" to end of valueList
            tell (first property list item whose kind is list)
                tell (first property list item whose kind is record)
                    copy value of property list item "ElementInfoName" to end of nameList
                    copy value of property list item "ElementStatusState" to end of valueList
                    tell (first property list item whose kind is list)
                        tell (first property list item whose kind is record)
                            copy value of property list item "ElementInfoName" to end of nameList
                            copy value of property list item "ElementStatusState" to end of valueList
                        end tell
                    end tell
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, Ted. I figured that this would be pretty easy as far as diving into a plist file and pulling info.

Comment: I am having an issue with the first part though. I'm getting an error "Finder got an error: AppleEvent handler failed." so of course no info here what might be the cause. Not sure if it's the "by modification date" setting? I will point out though that I see every file is preceded by a 9 digit number that is in order. So maybe it can be by name. I tried changing the sort to "name" but that still gave me the same error.

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8um0D.jpg

I basically just need the last key in the file, regardless what came before it.

Comment: @ChrisRoy: Well, I tested this script on my machine and I didn't get that error, so I'm not sure where it's coming from. `sort ... by modification date` is perfectly valid syntax, so it's not that. Which OS are you on? Maybe there's something in the AppleScript version that's going sideways...

Comment: @ChrisRoy: Could you be more specific about the phrase 'the last key in the file'? In plist files, only arrays have a predefined order; key order for other elements is arbitrary, and is not guaranteed to be the same in every case. Either tell me explicitly you want the last element of the top-level array, or tell me the key-name of the value you want recovered.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion and I really appreciate your patience. What I'm realizing is that I really need to read all the "ElementStatusState" keys into an array/list so that I can further analyze them.

Comment: It would help if you posted a plain-text version of that plist (images are a pain to read, and without the text I can't really test anything), but from what I can see, it looks as though the structure of the file is a nested set of dictionaries representing different things, where each dictionary contains an  `ElementStatusState` representing something or other. So what you'd want to extract is the key-name of each dictionary, with the corresponding ESS value for that dictionary: does that sound correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct and hopefully fairly easy. Take note that there can be different numbers of video file being encoded (and looks like there's a dictionary for each?) so please keep that in mind.

Comment: hmm haven't figured out how to post a doc... stand by.

Comment: Heres a link https://bigpicturesf.box.com/s/k91u2xs3p41ipfno2b6nsmihv8sgt3b3

Comment: Edits made to the answer. This works on my device. I still don't see why you're getting an 'Apple Event handler failed' error; that's usually reserved for commands that aren't implemented in the called app, but that shouldn't be a problem here.

Comment: Fantastic gets the info that I needed! Thank you very much. The first part still throws an error but I've seen some other examples of finding a file in a folder and maybe I'll hit on one that works the best. Thanks again.

Comment: Figured out the error. I was trying to ~ to the current usr folder, but POSIX wants an absolute path. My mistake.